# trigger fetch if there's query params on route

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm Trying to filter records And I'm putting the filter params on route `this.$route.query`.

I have the filter on `fetch` :

```js
  async fetch() {
     this.triggerFilter = true;
      const query = {
        limit: this.pageSize,
        page: this.currentPage,
        field: this.field,
        lang: this.lang,
        cost: this.range,
      };
      if (!this.field) delete query.field;
      if (!this.lang) delete query.lang;
      this.$router.push(
        this.localePath({
          name: "all-slug",
          query: query,
        })
      );

      this.sorted = true;
      let params = [];
      for (let key in query)
        params.push(
          `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(query[key])}`
        );
      const queryString = params.join("&");

      await this.$store.dispatch(
        "myaction",
        encodeURI("/api/ap" + this.$route.params.slug + "?" + queryString+'&locale='+this.$i18n.locale)
      );
        this.triggerFilter = false
  },
```

I'm trying to make the function trigger if there are query parameters on the route if the user refreshed the page .

If i refresh the page and console log `this.$route.query` on fetch function  i get `{}`

I just don't want to use mounted or created to call a method .

any idea how can this be achieved?

I'm using nuxt 2.

Comment: You're sharing some code but it's totally irrelevant since we don't know why your `console.log` is returning `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the route params with this.$route.params.{name of your param}. Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: This should probably be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of code totally works.

```html
<template>
  <div>nice index page</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  async fetch() {
    if (this.$route.query.trigger === 'yes') {
      const call = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
      const response = await call.json()
      console.log('response', response)
    }
  },
  fetchOnServer: false, // set this if you want to debug the call only on client-side
}
</script>
```

Type `http://localhost:3000/?trigger=yes` if you want `fetch` to call JSON placeholder's API.
Type `http://localhost:3000/?trigger=no` (or whatever) otherwise.

---

As shown below

[image]

[image]

PS: this also totally works with `this.$route.params` too of course.